# Unity Android libs folder

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

There is a standard way to build Unity applications for Android - to put all jars, manifests and resources in Assets/Plugins/Android forlder.

But we want to componentize or project and to put all staff, related to the certain component, to the folder such as Assets/Packages/Component1/Android

Is there a way to do this with the latest Unity version?

Answer (score 1):

Unity recognizes Plugins folders wherever they are. So, if this is what you want, you can put your stuff into *Assets/Packages/Component1/Plugins/Android* and put all of those libs there.

Example hierarchy may be.

*Assets/Packages/Component1/Scripts* - all of the c# scripts here
*Assets/Packages/Component1/Plugins/Android* - android libs here
*Assets/Packages/Component1/Plugins/iOS* - ios libs here

etc...